# Activity tracking usecase for login tracking

Tags: database, android-activity, use-case

Creating an activity tracking system for a social site. All user activiti from pooint of login til logoff are to be tracked. This means the first use case is the user's login. Every activity will have the same format so once I figure out how to track one activity then I can create chema for all activities. Currently for login I have steps like:

Two solutions I have:
Activity 1: User attempts to login
Activity 2 A: User has successfully logged in
Activity 2 B: User failed to login.
Activity 2 B A: User failed to login due to invalid password
Activity 2 B B: User failed to login due to locked account.

OR

Activty 1: User login - with result = Pass or Fail and if Fail reason = flag_id of reason.

Accordingly I have to create the schema. For now I have it like this:
activity_id
object_id (fk)
session_id (fk)
user_id  (fk)
flag_id  (fk)
created_dt
friend_id  (fk)
result (pass/fail)

But ofcourse this a work in progress.

Comment: PHP but langiage should not matter. It is a social site and I need to implement user activity tracking so deciding about how to create schema to log activities.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this requirement is simply stating (well, attempting to state it simply) that there should be an audit of login attempts to the system, to include reasons for failed logins.  The table might look like this:

```
LoginAudit
  ID (some kind of primary key, whatever your standards are)
  UserID (FK to whatever table holds users, or whatever uniquely identifies a user)
  LoginTime (time stamp of attempt)
  IsSuccessful (bit, true or false, was the login successful?)
  Status (FK to a table of known statuses, or just the status itself for a flat de-normalized structure, indicating "success" or a reason for failure, such as "invalid password" or "account locked")
  (more relevant data, such as user's IP or location, etc.)...
```

This would be a write-heavy table (so watch the indexing) and data shouldn't ever be changed.  You might want to put some triggers on it to prevent updates, etc.

On a side note, and this may go without saying but I feel I should say it anyway just in case, make sure you don't present the login failure reason to the user when you're storing it here.  All the user should see is that the login failed.  The reason for the failed login gives an attacker additional information that they can use to manipulate the system.

Comment: This is 1 usecase part of the user's activity tracking module. It is a social site and I need to track all user activities from the point of login till they logoff, but based on the activity design I have to create the schema (table colunms to hold all the system activities)

Comment: Unless you are suggesting to have 1 table for each possible activity?

Comment: @Mdillion: I'm not suggesting that, since that wasn't in the question.  The original question was just about tracking user login attempts, to include reasons for failed logins.  If there's more to this, you may want to add it to the question and being as explicit as possible.